# create webrequest object once for lifetime of application

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest

Should I create webrequest object once for the lifetime of application and reuse it every time to get the requeststraem to post the data on server or should I create new object every time I want to post data.

Presently I just have to post the data on server all the time and nothing concern with reading the response from server.

Can some one please explain the detailes pros and cons of this

Comment: You must close a connection even if you dont read any data from the response. Moreover, status code will be read from the response even if you dont try to get any data from this response.

Answer (score 1):

A single `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` only executes a request once.

If you call `GetResponse()` two or more times, the first time will execute the request and return a response. Subsequent calls will return the original response.

If you're trying to post the exact same HTTP request multiple times, you need a new object for every request.

However if you want to use the newer `System.Net.Http` APIs, you can have a single global `HttpClient` that manages multiple `HttpRequestMessage`/`HttpResponseMessage` objects.

Comment: Is there a source for this statement "A single System.Net.HttpWebRequest only executes a request once."? Official docs or anything, Becausem thism ight be true, yet I have found no single mention of that in MS docs.